# Should I be able to hear audio using X11 forwarding?

Tags: ubuntu, audio, xorg

I use a portable virtual box (running Ubuntu) at work. I funnel my web browsing through an ssh link back to my home PC. Today I was playing around with X11 forwarding to access applications running on my home PC. I played around and eventually got the X11 forwarding to work. Xclock launched, open office worked. Everything seemed hunky doory.

Then I thought to myself... I wonder if its possible for me to access all my mp3's and have the audio streamed to my work PC. I could save myself from the chore of copying files to cds/usb keys/whatever.

However, it seems though that no matter what media player I choose, audio is not forwarded. My first attempt was with rhythmbox. I launched the app and noticed the app would load and display correctly but no audio was forwarded. It would show that playback was occuring but I would not hear any audio. I assume it must have been playing out of my speakers at home (and probably was making my dog nuerotic). I thought this may have been a rhythmbox issue, however other apps also failed.

Does X11 only forward the video/GUI components and not audio?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

X11 does has nothing to do with audio.  Its purpose is to serve video only.

**However**, it appears that PulseAudio can [piggyback onto a forwarded X11 session](http://colin.guthr.ie/2009/08/sound-on-linux-is-confusing-defuzzing-part-2-pulseaudio/) over ssh and forward the audio as well!

Comment: PulseAudio and ESD are "sound servers" that are designed to be an analogue of the X-Window's X-server.  it's nice when they work automagically.

Comment: The piggyback link is currrently broken.

Comment: Are there any up-to-date instructions for Ubuntu? `paprefs` just has a bunch of grayed out checkboxes.

Comment: archive link for piggyback: https://web.archive.org/web/20210618004002/http://colin.guthr.ie/2009/08/sound-on-linux-is-confusing-defuzzing-part-2-pulseaudio/

Comment: @AaronFranke, did you find anything recent for Ubuntu?

Comment: No, I was not able to get audio working with X11 forwarding.