# Video running in SSH

Tags: ssh, video-streaming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I be able to hear audio using X11 forwarding?](https://superuser.com/questions/61703/should-i-be-able-to-hear-audio-using-x11-forwarding)

I want to run video on others computers through SSH in linux from other end. How can I do that? I'm using VLC but it plays audio file and unabkle to play audio file.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/61703/should-i-be-able-to-hear-audio-using-x11-forwarding

Answer (score 1):

Plain-ol' `ssh -X` may be able to locally display the GUI of a remotely executed movie player, but it will not be able to also tunnel the sound back to your local machine...

However, even the remotely running video will not show up in a smooth fashion (not even when you are in a LAN).

What you need to overcome that is either [FreeNX](http://freenx.berlios.de/) or, more reliably, and very easy to set up: [NoMachine NX](http://www.nomachine.com/products.php).

The core technology for both is developed by NoMachine.com. It compresses remote X11 traffic very efficiently, and is also able to tunnel sound. NoMachine released the core code under the GPL license, but they also sell some commercial products on top of it. FreeNX uses the GPL license to create their thing, but it is not well maintained at all...

I'd recommend to try NoMachine's "NX Free Edition", which is free for private and commercial use for up to 2 concurrent user sessions per installation.